# Table View not reloading in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

i have a add favorite button feature in my app. when a user adds a shop to his favorites, it goes to his profile.

now the table view works but when a i click the favorite button and navigate to the profile viewcontroller i dont see the new data which is the shop i favorited. but when i close and open the app, the shop becomes visible.

i want it to be once a user favorites something it will be shown immediately in his profile

i used `tableView.reloadData()` but it is not working. what am i doing wrong?

here is my code:

```
  func loadData(){// i call thiss function later in the viewDidLoad()
       let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid

    
    db.collection("Favorites").whereField("usersID", isEqualTo: userID).getDocuments(){
           querySnapshot, error in
           if let error = error {
               print(error.localizedDescription)
           }else
           {
            if(querySnapshot!.isEmpty){
                //here put you didn't favorite any shops image/text
                
            }else{
               self.shops = querySnapshot!.documents.compactMap({addShop(dictionary: $0.data())})
               DispatchQueue.main.async {
                
                self.faveList.reloadData()
                print("reloaded")
                
               }
        }
           }
       }
    
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

viewDidLoad() is called only once when UIViewController created. You can try calling it on viewWillAppear() method